# ¿Como puedo mantener los datos de un componente hijo? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

estoy empezando en React Native y quisiera saber, como puedo mantener los datos que estan en el estado de un componente hijo.

Estoy haciendo un aplicacion que genere una cierta cantidad de mesas.Por dentro de estas mesas, tengo un menu, y dentro de este menu, tengo componentes que se encargan de la logica  para poder hacer las suma de los platos que se sirvieron, y cuanto es el total.
Pero cuando regreso a la pagina donde estan mis mesas, todos los resultados de mis cuentas que estaba en cada mesa, se borraron.

**Este es el componente que se encarga de crear cada mesa**

```js
export default function Cuentas() {
  const { mesa, handleClick } = useContext(MesaContext);
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <View style={style.bottonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={style.FAB} onPress={handleClick}>
          <Text style={style.FabText}> Nueva mesa</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={mesa}
        keyExtractor={(mesa) => String(mesa.id)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Mesa mesas={item} />}
        horizontal={false}
        style={style.FlatList}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Este es el Componente que renderiza un componente que esta encargado de renderizar todos los platos**

```js
export default function CuentaMesa(props) {
  const {
    route: { params },
    navigation,
  } = props;
  const { mesa } = useContext(MesaContext);

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <Text style={style.TitleMesa}>{params.name}</Text>
      <Platos />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Aqui es donde se renderizan todos los platos*

```js
export default function Platos() {
  const [platos, setPlatos] = useState(platosService);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <View style={style.Text}>
        {platos.map(plato => {
          return (
            <View key={plato.id} style={style.platosContainer}>
              <View style={style.platosView}>
                <Text style={style.platoTitle}>{plato.name}</Text>
                <Text style={style.platoPrice}>${plato.price}</Text>
              </View>
              <View>
                <Plato price={plato.price} />
              </View>

            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

**Aqui es donde estan los inputs, que sirven para hacer toda la logica, quiero que los datos de que estan aqui (El resultado de cada operacion que se hizo con el input) se guarde, para que al momento de salir al array, donde estan las mesas y al volver a entrar, esa informacion este ahi**

```js
export default function Plato(props) {
    const [input, setInput] = useState(null)
    const [suma, setSuma] = useState(null)
    const { price } = props
    console.log(price);
    console.log(input)
    const sumaPrecios = () => {
        setSuma(Number(input) * price)
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{price}</Text>
            <Text>Suma:{suma}</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder='Cantidad' style={style.input} value={input} onChangeText={setInput} />
            <Button title='Total' onPress={sumaPrecios} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

De ante mano, muchas gracias por su ayuda